# Merge PDF in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf, pdf-manipulation

Not able to locate requested PDF

Here is my function:-

```
function genpdf()
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('PDFMerger');
    $a=$_POST['a'];
    $b=$_POST['b'];
    $pdf = new PDFMerger;
    $pdf->addPDF("samplepdfs/$a")
    ->addPDF("samplepdfs/$b")
    ->merge('file', 'http://localhost/student/samplepdfs/genpdf.pdf');
}
```

I need to merge different PDF into one. I am using **fpdf** & **fpdi**. I want it to be done with **codeigniter**. Another solutions(different methods than mentioned above) are also welcome.

Comment: Add pdfs one by one and add debug output to find out exactly which pdf could not be found.

Comment: How did you could use PDFMerger in CodeIgniter? Adding like a thirdparty library gives me bunch of errors.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to check if pdf file exists before trying to add it, as you are fetching the pdf filename from `POST` data, like:

```
...
$a=$_POST['a'];
$b=$_POST['b'];

$error = false;
$errorMsg = "";
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
if( file_exists("samplepdfs/$a") ) {
    $pdf->addPDF("samplepdfs/$a");
}
else {
    $error = true;
    $errorMsg .="File:".$a." not found <br />";
}
if( file_exists("samplepdfs/$b") ) {
    $pdf->addPDF("samplepdfs/$b")
}
else {
    $error = true;
    $errorMsg .="File:".$b." not found";
}

//merge pdf if no error
if( !$error ) {
    $pdf->merge('file', 'http://localhost/student/samplepdfs/genpdf.pdf');
}
else {
    echo $errorMsg;
}
```